# Is it possible to create a table within a <select> tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a select statement where each option contains quantity and price for an item we're selling. I thought I would create a table where for every row, quantity would be in one , and price would be in the other . I can't seem to get this to work in a select statement. I also tried using  tags with a float-right and float-left and this didn't work either. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Oddly, on trying under an html doctype, a `<table>` contained within a `<select>` element validated (at the W3C's http://validator.w3.org/) ...this surprises me =/

Comment: ricebowl: ? `document type does not allow element "TABLE" here` for me, as expected.

Comment: I entered it by text-input, so I can't link to a live demo. Maybe tomorrow I'll try again with a full document and see what happens; being considered valid surprised me, so maybe I screwed it up somehow... I'm glad your attempt succeeded in, um, failing; the world feels less-strange now =)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with plain vanilla HTML. You'll need to grasp Javascript to mimic such a dropdown with help of other HTML elements and a good shot of CSS. You can get [here](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/) some ideas what's all possible with good JS (actually, [jQuery](http://jquery.com)) and CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've done with plain html is to just add the appropriate number of `&nbsp;` to line everything up correctly.  JavaScript is probably the better way to go though.

Comment: This would certainly be a good way to render the basic markup version, before ‘progressive enhancement’.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in plain HTML - you'd have to look at a javascript combo box replacement.

Comment: A combobox is not the same as a dropdown. A combobox is an editable dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the above answers, you could just make the text of the options to make sense as english ..

something like

```
<select name="..">

<option value="1">1 item for xx price</option>
<option value="2">2 items for xxx price</option>
....
<option value="5">5 item for xxxx price</option>

</select>
```